# Separating string-XML into string variables | Serialization?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a string in the program that stores xml-style text, I would like to assign

I can use only C# and only  .NET 2.0 i .NET 3.5

```
  <Document>
    <IdSprawy>vff24</IdSprawy>
    <TaskNumber>0173196</TaskNumber>
    <TestText>ferf24</TestText>
   </Document>
```

I want final result: (theoretically, such results would be)

```
string Id = 'vff24';
string TaskNumber = '0173196';
string TestText = 'ferf24';
```

I don't know completely how to do it

I start writting sth like this:

```
    public class A_StartActSerScr
    {
        public static void OnFormExit()
        {
            string TextXML;  // this xml


        // here i want to assign data from xml to variables via the "Document" class
        // for exp.
            string IdSprawyX = 'vff24';
            string TaskNumberX = '0173196';
            string TestTextX = 'ferf24';


        }
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Document
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("IdSprawy")]
        public string IdSprawyField{ get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("TaskNumber")]
        public string TaskNumberField{ get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("TestText")]
        public string TestTextField { get; set; }
    }
```

I dont know hot to write classes correctly:

and how to write deserialize function:

Comment: `"IdSprawy"` should be just `"Id"`, as in your xml.

Comment: Why write a deserialization-function, when there is `XmlSerializer.DeSerialize(myObjec)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645964/deserializing-xml-from-string) answers your deserialization question using XmlSerializer.

Another option would be to use [Linq to Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) to parse your XML string. The below code isn't necessarily optimized, but it parses the xml into separate values.

```
string xml = "<Document><Id>vff24</Id><TaskNumber>0173196</TaskNumber><TestText>ferf24</TestText></Document>";
var xEl = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(xml);

string id = xEl.Element("Id").Value;
string taskNumber = xEl.Element("TaskNumber").Value;
string testText = xEl.Element("TestText").Value;
```